Generation of the notion of singular value in Banach space
Recall that the singular values of a $d \times d$ real or complex matrix $A$ are the non-negative square roots of the eigenvalues of the positive semidefinite matrix $A^{*} A$, and are denoted $\sigma_{1}(A), \ldots, \sigma_{d}(A)$ in decreasing order, with repetition in the case of multiplicity.
we principally use one specific generalization, namely Gelfand numbers to analogue the concept of singular value in general Banach space : if $A$ is a bounded linear operator acting on a Banach space $(V,|\cdot|)$, then for each integer $k \geq 1$ we define the $k^{\text {th }}$ Gelfand number of $A$ to be the quantity
$$
c_{k}(A):=\inf \left\{|A|_{F} \mid: F \text { is a closed }(k-1) \text {-dimensional subspace of } V\right\} \text {. }
$$
Example : Let $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})=\left\{\left(a_{1}, a_{2}, \cdots\right): a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i} a_{i}^{2}<\infty\right\}$ and let $\left\{e_{i}\right\}_{i \geq 1} \subset \ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ denote the standard basis. Define $T: \ell^{2}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ to be the linear operator for which $T e_{k}=2^{-k} e_{k+1}$ for all $k \geq 1$. Then, $T$ is compact, injective, and a straightforward computation yields
$$
\frac{c_{1}\left(T^{n}\right)}{c_{2}\left(T^{n}\right)}=2^{n}
$$
I want to ask how this equation in the example came about?

What are $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$?

I think the original text here was written incorrectly, they should be c1 and c2

I don't konw how to count when k=1,F is a closed 0-dimensional subspace of V.
